# user input for removing multiple elements in a list

Tags: list, loops, python-2.7

I have read and re-read list comprehensions and loops and I guess these are not what I think they are.

I am trying to find info in a bunch of junk by turning the junk into a list, sorting, removing junk, as defined by the user. User enters a char, all the matching chars should be removed. Repeat.

However it only removes one of the matching chars, not all of them. I believe the problem lies in the way I'm calling the function to start over, but I guess function (and class calling for that matter) doesn't work like I think it does

Here's as close as I have gotten after hours :( I am totally noob at this so go easy on me please. Thanks.

```
junk = """
(+*]_}%+(%[{)]({#[+$&&[^@{&#!@%)!+&}$@+@[+&_*!$(+#*%!+$@{{^**{)(]*$(}+
!$%}$$}+@^$$%{}{#!(%[]$!*}+(]!%{(^{&^{$[$)]&&^+{+%!#[([%^!{]]#^@!{#(&]@_$*_&!%(!
+_+}%@#{_}^#*)%*(*}*![}[%_[[^@$&%)([*{_${)$^^_!+}{)!)@_[*$_}*}$#[+}{]*+!^])}&{+#
+!@!^*@}!}&{]*#^@}_[)}#@%!_*#!$}!)[(${+^&!{[&&&*[{}+*+(#+_[}{$$)#([*!)%@^%_]#%$$
(++^+&)}*_&%@#[^^+^&@_%]+$%$#$*)@!(]*+@]}%$$}$(#$&^(%[*([&]*^&}(!#{&_}^(*{(+$#}}
(&_+][&_@)$&$&^[_$(++$^}]&^^*(+*!&#_$]*+@!]+{%^_*+!&}@$!#^{+_#([+@(((*+)[()__}(^
@)](+[$*_(]*$[[&@^(_*#(*&!^{+]_%)_)^[}@]#]%#@+^+[%{_*{!)}#$@#)_$!_(!*+#}%%}+$&$[
%&]!{{%*_!*}&)}$**_{*!#%[[#]!](^^$![#[[*}%(_#^^!%))!_^@)@**@}}(%%{#*%@(((]^%^![&
}!)$]&($)@](+(#{$)_%^%_^^#][{*[)%}+[##(##^{$}^]#&(&*{)%)&][&{]&#]}[[^^&[!#}${@_(
#@}&$[[%]_&$+)$!%{(}$^$}*
"""

junklist = list(junk)


def find():
    junklist.sort()
    print junklist
    x = str(raw_input("what do you want to remove from the list?> "))
    return x

def deleteChars(x):
    while len(junklist) > 0:
        if x in junklist:
            junklist.remove(x)
            find()
        else:
            print "not in junklist"
            find()  

x =find()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the program to delete ALL occurrences of the character entered. Now just modify it to make it recursive to your wish. If you need more help, let me know.

```
    junk = """
(+*]_}%+(%[{)]({#[+$&&[^@{&#!@%)!+&}$@+@[+&_*!$(+#*%!+$@{{^**{)(]*$(}+
!$%}$$}+@^$$%{}{#!(%[]$!*}+(]!%{(^{&^{$[$)]&&^+{+%!#[([%^!{]]#^@!{#(&]@_$*_&!%(!
+_+}%@#{_}^#*)%*(*}*![}[%_[[^@$&%)([*{_${)$^^_!+}{)!)@_[*$_}*}$#[+}{]*+!^])}&{+#
+!@!^*@}!}&{]*#^@}_[)}#@%!_*#!$}!)[(${+^&!{[&&&*[{}+*+(#+_[}{$$)#([*!)%@^%_]#%$$
(++^+&)}*_&%@#[^^+^&@_%]+$%$#$*)@!(]*+@]}%$$}$(#$&^(%[*([&]*^&}(!#{&_}^(*{(+$#}}
(&_+][&_@)$&$&^[_$(++$^}]&^^*(+*!&#_$]*+@!]+{%^_*+!&}@$!#^{+_#([+@(((*+)[()__}(^
@)](+[$*_(]*$[[&@^(_*#(*&!^{+]_%)_)^[}@]#]%#@+^+[%{_*{!)}#$@#)_$!_(!*+#}%%}+$&$[
%&]!{{%*_!*}&)}$**_{*!#%[[#]!](^^$![#[[*}%(_#^^!%))!_^@)@**@}}(%%{#*%@(((]^%^![&
}!)$]&($)@](+(#{$)_%^%_^^#][{*[)%}+[##(##^{$}^]#&(&*{)%)&][&{]&#]}[[^^&[!#}${@_(
#@}&$[[%]_&$+)$!%{(}$^$}*
"""

junklist = list(junk)


def find():
    junklist.sort()
    print junklist
    x = str(raw_input("what do you want to remove from the list?> "))
    deleteChars(x)
    return x



def deleteChars(x):
    if x in junklist:
      a = [y for y in junklist if y != x]
      print a
    else:
      print 'not in junklist'


x=find()
```

Comment: I cannot figure out where to put my while loop to make this recursive. What ends up happening is i keeping going through the same loop so the chars we essentially removed from junklist when we created list(a) are back...I guess this is a whole new problem? Thank you for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

Change your if into a for statement.
For y in junklist:
  Then just check if x==y. If so delete that.

Comment: hmm I cannot get that to work either. Do you have an example that I could study?